# How to stop passing value from one form to other in formclosing event?

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

I got 2 forms (form1, form2). I can pass values from form2 to form1, but the main problem is, when I just close the form2, he will pass the values anyway, so I got empty values in form1.
 For example: I add a value of 2000 euros to form 1 textbox&label, and then when I open one more time the form2, and leave the texbox clear and radiobutt unchecked,then close the form2 with the red X closing button, the form1 values of 2000 euros will disappear.
Here's the source code of the passing values and buttons:

FORM2

```
private string pss;
public string Passvalue
{  

    get { return pss; }
    set { pss = value; }
}
private string pss2;  
public string Passvalue2
{
    get { return pss2; }
    set { pss2 = value; }
}

public void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//The passvalue button
{
    string eur="EUR";
    Passvalue = ukupnaCifraTB.Text;//textbox form2=the number sender
    ukupnaCifraTB.Text = String.Empty;



    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        radioButton1.Text = eur;
        Passvalue2 = radioButton2.Text;
    }

    this.Close();
}
```

Here's form1:

```
private string backvalue;
public string BackedValue
{
    get { return backvalue; }
    set { backvalue = value; }           
}

private string backedText;
public string BackedText
{
    get { return backedText; }
    set { backedText =  value; }
}

public void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(); 
    f2.ShowDialog();
    trenutnoStanjeTB.Text = f2.Passvalue;//trenutnostanjeTB=textbox(form1)=gets number from form2
    DinEuLab1.Text = f2.Passvalue2;//dineulab1=label form1=gets the eur text
    DinEuLab2.Text = f2.Passvalue2;

}
```

What I need to change/add to resolve my problem? **I want that when I once pass the values, and then open the form2 and close it, to not send the empty values to form1.**

Comment: Please format your question so it's more readable.  Use paragraphs, spacing etc.

Comment: You might want to format this wall-of-text into a human readable question.

Comment: Have you tried just validating the values before writing them back?  That is at the point you are passing the values look at the values first and decide whether or not you want to do it?

Comment: Edited, better now? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple query for emptiness could resolve your issue. At the point where your Form2 is closed and you try to assign the `Passvalues` to the `Textboxes` of `Form1`, just check whether there are valid values in `f2.Passvalue` and `f2.Passvalue2`. If they are not empty assign them, otherwise let the old value remain

```
trenutnoStanjeTB.Text = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f2.Passvalue) ? f2.Passvalue : trenutnoStanjeTB.Text;

DinEuLab1.Text = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f2.Passvalue2) ? f2.Passvalue2 : DinEuLab1.Text;
```

and so on

Comment: can you explain it better please? Like, where I need to put these codes...

Comment: @drunken-sailor I tried, see my edit. You need to make the query in the `Btn1_Click` event of Form 1

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your question is unreadable and all over the place. Secondly, it seems you haven't made any attempt to validate these values or at least to show us what you have tried to solve your problem. You can easily try one of the following

1. If you want Form2 to stop if a value is blank

   ```
   if (Passvalue2.Trim().Length <= 0)    
   {       
       MessageBox.Show("There is no Value");
       return;
   }
   ```
2. If you want to offer a default value when a blank is detected and continue the process, you could do the following

   ```
   Passvalue2 = radioButton2.Text.Trim().Length > 0 ? radioButton2.Text.Trim() : "SOME DEFAULT VALUE";
   ```

**EDIT**

3. You can also just change your From1 Btn1_Click event as follows

   ```
   public void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

   {
       Form2 f2 = new Form2(); 
       f2.ShowDialog();
       if ((f2.Passvalue.Length > 0) && (f2.Passvalue2.Length > 0))
       {
           trenutnoStanjeTB.Text = f2.Passvalue;//trenutnostanjeTB=textbox(form1)=gets number from form2
           DinEuLab1.Text = f2.Passvalue2;//dineulab1=label form1=gets the eur text
           DinEuLab2.Text = f2.Passvalue2;
       }

   }
   ```

If you want to check Passvalue and Passvalu2 individually, just split up the condition on the if statement. Here i'm assuming you want BOTH values to have something before you assign them.

Comment: I want that, when I close the form2, while the textbox is blank and radiobutton unchecked, to stop passing empty values to form1 becouse they override my values entered and sent before. So i don't want to block the closing of the form, I just want that when I close the blank form2 to do nothing in form1.
Your first code is for formclosing event or?

Comment: Hi @drunken-sailor, have a look at my edit. I've added new code after reading your comment. That can also be an alternative. Give it a try and accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: your edited code works, but, the app breaks after I close form2. I don' know why? I got error message lik this: "NullReferenceException was unhandled" and the error is with the code: if ((f2.Passvalue.Length > 0) && (f2.Passvalue2.Length > 0))